# Скрыть блок при клике вне

Tags: javascript

Необходимо скрыть блок,при клике вне него, если кликаю на крестик, то все нормально закрывается, если кликаю вне него, то задний фон остается затемнен и никуда кликнуть нельзя, вот код крестика:

```
 document.getElementById('cancel').onclick=function(){
        var container = document.getElementById('prompt-form-container');
        hideCover();
        container.style.display = 'none';         
    }
```

Вот код, чтоб скрывать при клики вне блока

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
window.onclick = function(event) {

    if (event.target == modal) {

        modal.style.display = "none";


}
hidecover();
    }
```

Функция

```
function hideCover() {
      document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('cover-div'));
    }
```

Код блока:

```
 <div class="wallets-deposit" id="myModal">
                    <div class="wallets-deposit__inner" >
                        <div class="wallets__p-title">
                            <h5>Withdrawal</h5>
                            <div>Available: <span id="span_in_title_withdrawal"></span></div>
                                <div class="fragment" id="cancel"> <span class="closebtn" style="position: relative; bottom:auto; right: 10px" >&times;</span></div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: затемнение - очевидно какой-то overlay, посмотрите что у него за класс/айди/тег (селектор в общем) и так же скрывайте его вместе с блоком.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не задавайте один вопрос несколько раз. Если хотите добавить деталей или уточнить формулировку - отредактируйте существующий вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == document.getElementById('cover-div'))
    document.getElementById('cancel').onclick();
}
```

Comment: Так при клике на крестик все нормально закрывается, проблема при клике вне блока

Comment: @Midnight не понял, это что  значит?

Comment: В всплывающем блоке есть крестик, с помощью которого блок успешно закрывается, но мне нужно, чтобы при клике вне блока он тоже закрывался. Но когда кликаю, фон позади все равно остается темным и кликнуть никуда нельзя

Comment: @Midnight Вы использовали мой код?

Comment: Да. окно вовсе перестало скрываться при клике вне

Comment: Добавил код блока в вопрос

Comment: @Midnight сделайте работающий пример